# Ruby Youtube API upload failed with "Missing access token"

Tags: ruby, youtube, google-api-client

I've not found answer for this question and I am not able to upload video to youtube by Ruby.

I am using "Upload a video" from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby

JSON file with client-ID, secret etc. was generated from google developers console and contains proper data.

```
C:\Projects\youtube>C:\Ruby\bin\ruby.exe C:/Projects/youtube/upload.rb --file VID_20131207_172637_752.mp4
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/signet-0.6.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:1009:in `generate_authenticated_request': Missing access token. (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/request.rb:241:in `to_env'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/request.rb:161:in `send'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:648:in `block (2 levels) in execute!'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:645:in `block in execute!'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:636:in `execute!'
        from C:/Projects/youtube/upload.rb:75:in `main'
        from C:/Projects/youtube/upload.rb:93:in `<main>'
```

Any case from this post [Why does  Google's Custom Search API say that I'm missing an access token when using the Ruby client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013648/why-does-googles-custom-search-api-say-that-im-missing-an-access-token-when-u) do not give positive results.
When i try to use `client.authorization = nil` I get following reply from google:

```
C:\Projects\youtube>C:\Ruby\bin\ruby.exe C:/Projects/youtube/upload.rb --file VID_20131207_172637_752.mp4
    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
       }
      ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Login Required"
     }
    }
```

Platform: 
Win7 64bit 
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x64-mingw32] 
google-api-client (0.8.6)   - also I tried 0.9.pre3 and get the same behavior.

When debugging client.authorization and file_storage.authorization objects contain uninitialized data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a bit of code snippet of the file `upload.rb` where you think the error is getting generated.

Comment: Errors are always generated when calling`videos_insert_response = client.execute!(
        :api_method => youtube.videos.insert,
        :body_object => body,
        :media => Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(opts[:file], 'video/*'),
        :parameters => {
            :uploadType => 'resumable',
            :part => body.keys.join(',')
        }
    )`

Comment: Given code on Ruby is for YouTube Data API (v2)
YouTube Data API (v3) is current version and old Ruby code is not work I guess.